# Swift function to find first element of collection matching a predicate?

Tags: swift, collections

If `xs` is a collection and `pred` is a closure that returns a `Bool`, is there a built-in function that does the following?

```
xs.filter(pred).first
```

This gets the first element of a collection matching the predict, or `nil` if there is no match. Not interested in the index, but the element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't, but you can write one yourself like this:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func first(@noescape pred: Generator.Element throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Generator.Element? {
        return try filter(pred).first
    }
}
```

EDIT: This version isn't optimal, since the `filter` creates a whole new array, even though only the first element would be needed. As noted by Martin R, `lazy.filter` also doesn't work for. This would be necessary to make it work with `lazy`:

```
extension CollectionType {
    func first(pred: Generator.Element -> Bool) -> Generator.Element? {
        return lazy.filter(pred).first
    }
}
```

Because:

- `@noescape` can't be used because `@noescape` means that the closure cannot escape the current function, which would be possible when passing it to the lazy `filter` (doesn't evaluate elements until it is asked to -> has to escape the predicate)
- `throws` can't be used because the filter is lazy -> errors wouldn't be thrown immediately, but rather when it is used the first time which would be when calling `first`, but `first` can't be throwing because it's a property. There are some discussions on making getters (and subscripts) throwing in future versions of Swift.
- `CollectionType` has to be used, because only `LazyCollectionType` has the `first` property.

So to really make it lazy and have all the `@noescape`, `throws` and `SequenceType`, you'd have to use an imperative approach:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func first(@noescape pred: Generator.Element throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Generator.Element? {
        for elem in self where try pred(elem) {
            return elem
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: `return try filter(pred).first` makes it compile. It is not optimal because *all* sequence elements are evaluated. For some reason, even `return try lazy.filter(pred).first` doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, what you want may look like this:

```
let array = [18, 12, 35, 11, 12, 44]
var first: Int?

for element in array where element == 12 {
    first = element
    break
}

print(first) // prints: Optional(12)
```

---

If you really need to set a predicate closure, you can use the following pattern:

```
let array = [18, 12, 35, 11, 12, 44]
var first: Int?

let predicateClosure = { (value: Int) -> Bool in
    return value == 12
}

for element in array where predicateClosure(element) {
    first = element
    break
}

print(first) // prints: Optional(12)
```

---

If you need to repeat these operations, you can refactor your code by using a `SequenceType` protocol extension:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Int {
    func getFirstWithPredicate(predicate: Int -> Bool) -> Int? {
        for element in self where predicate(element) {
            return element
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let array = [18, 12, 35, 11, 12, 44]
let predicateClosure: Int -> Bool = {
    return $0 == 12
}

let first = array.getFirstWithPredicate(predicateClosure)
print(first) // prints: Optional(12)
```

---

Note that you don't need your `predicate` closure parameter to escape your `getFirstWithPredicate(_:)` method here, so you can add the `@noescape` attribute before it (see [Nonescaping Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID546) for more details):

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Int {
    func getFirstWithPredicate(@noescape predicate: Int -> Bool) -> Int? {
        for element in self where predicate(element) {
            return element
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let array = [18, 12, 35, 11, 12, 44]
let predicateClosure = { $0 == 12 }

let first = array.getFirstWithPredicate(predicateClosure)
print(first) // prints: Optional(12)
```

---

If you want the previous code to work for any type of sequence, you can remove the `Int` constraint and redeclare your `getFirstWithPredicate(_:)` method like in the following example:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func getFirstWithPredicate(@noescape predicate: Generator.Element -> Bool) -> Generator.Element? {
        for element in self where predicate(element) {
            return element
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let intArray = [18, 12, 35, 11, 12, 44]
let firstInt = intArray.getFirstWithPredicate { $0 == 12 }
print(firstInt) // prints: Optional(12)

let stringArray = ["Car", "Boat", "Plane", "Boat", "Bike"]
let firstString = stringArray.getFirstWithPredicate { $0 == "Boat" }
print(firstString) // prints: Optional("Boat")
```

---

If you're using a `CollectionType` protocol conforming object (for example, an `Array`), you can easily get the last element that matches your predicate with the same `getFirstWithPredicate(_:)` declaration by using `reverse()`:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func getFirstWithPredicate(@noescape predicate: Generator.Element -> Bool) -> Generator.Element? {
        for element in self where predicate(element) {
            return element
        }
        return nil
    }
}

struct Toy {
    let name: String
    let price: Int
}

let array = [
    Toy(name: "Ball", price: 20),
    Toy(name: "Car", price: 12),
    Toy(name: "Plane", price: 35),
    Toy(name: "Boat", price: 12),
]

let lastToyWithMatchingPrice = array.reverse().getFirstWithPredicate { $0.price == 12 }
print(lastToyWithMatchingPrice) // prints: Optional(Toy(name: "Boat", price: 12))
```